# What does "unstaged changes after reset" mean in git?

Tags: git

I accidentally `add`ed a bunch of text files to my git repo and attempted to unstage them (prior to commit):

```
git reset dir/*.txt
```

When the command was run it said:

```
unstaged changes after reset:
dir2/file.h
dir4/file2.cc
...
```

The files had no relation to the reset wildcard. As far as I can tell, the files are still staged for commit as modified and appear to be intact.  What is git trying to tell me?

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: It has them not staged for commit.  Which is consistent with the message of course, but why did this result from the reset command?  They are files that have been under rev control for ages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git is trying to be helpful here—perhaps *overly* helpful, in this case.  The phrase *unstaged changes* is a way of thinking about things that is meant to make using Git simpler.  This doesn't always work, because Git is complicated.

Here's the underlying reality: Git has, at all times,<sup>1</sup> *three* copies of each file.  Two of these copies literally *can't* be seen, at least not with the file navigation tools that you normally use.

Two of these three copies make sense, when you think about what a commit is and does:

- Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, saved forever.  The snapshot version of the file is from how that file looked at the time you (or whoever) *made* the commit.  (Each commit also holds some other stuff—some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself—but we'll ignore that here.)
- *Because* each commit has a full snapshot of every file, the files stored inside commits aren't stored as ordinary everyday files.  If they were, your repository would grow enormously fat ridiculously quickly.
- So, the files inside Git commits are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  Because they're read-only, it's entirely safe for commits to *share* these copies of files.  Making a new commit with ten thousand files, but 9999 of them the same as the last commit, really just re-uses the 9999 files and snapshots only the one changed file.  And, if the file has been changed *back* to the way it was in some earlier commit, that last file is shared with the *earlier* commit, so that the new snapshot takes no space at all.<sup>2</sup>

The problem with all of the above is that the files inside commits are *completely unusable for getting any actual work done:* they can only be *read* by Git, and nothing—not even Git itself—can *write* to them.  So, to *use* a commit, Git has to copy it out, expanding the files from their special Git-only format into ordinary everyday files.  These everyday-form files go into what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

So this all makes sense: the two "active" copies of some file, such as `README.md` or whatever, are the *current commit version*—this one is read-only and is in whichever commit you've selected to be the current commit, and only Git can see and read it—and your *working tree* version, which isn't actually *in* Git.  Git has extract it into a work area, and you are now working with it, but it's not in the *repository*.  It got copied out of the repository; it may or may not have been changed since then.

Two copies are all we would really need, and other version control systems—that are not Git—stop here, with just the two "active" copies.  But for whatever reason, good or ill, Git doesn't stop here.  Git inserts, sort of *between* the frozen `README.md` and the useful one, a *third* copy.  This third copy is in something that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These three names are all names for the same thing.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, most times.  If you break things down fine enough—especially, if you use some of Git's non-user-facing tools—you can do fun tricks or whatever.  There are also so-called *bare* repositories, which don't have a work-tree at all, except if you assign one temporarily; that's another complication we'll just ignore here.

<sup>2</sup>Except, that is, for the space required to hold the metadata.  The details here get pretty sticky too.  The point of all of this is that by re-using old files, Git can keep its repository small.  Given the way the files get compressed, in some cases a Git repository with many commits is sometimes *smaller* than any checked-out version!

<sup>3</sup>Some internal parts of Git make a distinction between the *index*, which is usually the file `.git/index`, and the *cache*, which at that point is an in-memory data structure.  The rather ancient `git apply` command has two separate flags, `--index` and `--cached`, that do different things.  But `git rm --cached` really means *remove from the index;* here the words *index* and *cache* are truly synonymous, for instance.

---

#### What's in the index

Technically, what's in the index isn't the file itself: it's the file's *name*—the full name of the file as Git sees it, complete with forward slashes, such as `path/to/file.ext`—and a whole bunch of internal stuff, some of which you can see with `git ls-files --stage`.  (Try it, but be aware that it spills out lots of output without pausing.)

Putting the technical details aside, though, what the index *achieves* is that it holds your *proposed next commit*.  The files in the index are in the same *form* as those in commits—they're pre-compressed and pre-de-duplicated—but unlike the committed copy, Git can *overwrite* them, by removing *that* de-duplicated copy and making a new de-duplicated copy.

Initially, when you `git checkout` some particular commit—the latest or *tip commit* on branch `feature`, for instance—Git fills its index with the files *from* that commit, and also fills in your work-tree with those files.  **The result is that all three active copies match.**  The committed copy, which is read-only, matches the index copy.  The index copy, which can be replaced, matches both the committed copy and your work-tree copy.

As you do your work, you will modify some file(s).  These will naturally be *your* copies of the files, which are in a usable format.  Git doesn't *use* these files!  Git *created* them earlier, by extracting them from a commit, but other than that, Git just leaves these files for *you*.  If you've *changed* one, you need to tell Git to do something about its index / staging-area copy.

What you do is run `git add`.  This has Git *read* your work-tree copy, compress it, de-duplicate it against all the stored files, and update its index copy.  Now Git's index copy matches your work-tree copy.

Note that because there are *three* copies, you can get all three of them out of sync: just check out some commit, modify some file, run `git add` on that file, and then modify the file again.  Now the frozen-for-all-time committed copy is different from the index copy, which is the one you `add`-ed earlier, and your working copy is still different from that because you've changed it again without `git add`-ing.

#### `git status` works by doing two diffs

When you run `git status`, it first prints out some overall information that people find helpful, such as the current branch name,<sup>4</sup> how far this branch is "ahead" or "behind" some other branch or remote-tracking name, and so on.  Then it gets to the *files*.

The first set of files it lists—if it lists any here—are the ones it calls *staged for commit*.  What it's really doing, though, is *comparing the current commit to the index*.  For each file that is *the same*, it says nothing at all.  For each file that is *different*, it says *staged for commit*.

The second set of files it lists, if any again, are the ones it calls *not staged for commit*.  Again, though, what it's really doing is comparing its index to your work-tree.  For each file that is *the same*, it says nothing at all.  For each file that is *different*, it says *not staged for commit*.

---

<sup>4</sup>Git stores the current branch name in something it calls `HEAD`.  There's one `HEAD` for each work-tree, and one index for each work-tree; the main `HEAD` and index are `.git/HEAD` and `.git/index`, normally, and any added work-trees get a new pair.  You're not supposed to need to know this, but it's handy sometimes to just look at `.git/HEAD`—it's currently just a plain-text file—to get a good feel for this.  This might all change in the future, though: `HEAD` used to be a symbolic link, for instance.

---

#### `git reset`

The `git reset` command is complicated.<sup>5</sup>  We'll ignore most of the complications, and concentrate just on the kind of `git reset` you got when you ran:

```
git reset dir/*.txt
```

This particular kind of `git reset` is now something you can achieve with the new (since Git 2.23) `git restore`.  It copies files from the current commit, to Git's index, without touching your work-tree.<sup>6</sup>

When you did this, you had something find a list of file names.  This gets a bit complicated because the *something* might be your shell, or it might be Git, and if it's Git, the set of file names Git will find could be different from the set your shell will find.  For simplicity, let's just assume that the set of files found either way was the same: all the files that the shell would find with `dir/*.txt` are the same set of files that Git would find matching against `dir/*.txt` in the current commit.  So Git copied all of these files from the current commit, into Git's index.

If they were already in Git's index—as that version of that file—this has no effect.  But wherever any file in Git's index / staging-area was *different*—presumably because you'd used `git add` on it, after changing *your* copy—this overwrote the updated index copy, setting it back to match the committed copy instead.  So this has the effect of undoing any `git add`s you ran earlier, for files matching `dir/*.txt`.

**Having done that, `git reset` now does a partial `git status`.**  That is, it compares *every* file in Git's index vs the copy of that same file in your work-tree.  For those that are *different*, Git lists them out as "unstaged".  Git didn't touch `dir2/file.h` in Git's index, but it was already different in your work-tree than it was in Git's index.  So `git reset`'s output here includes it.  The same goes for the other listed files.

---

<sup>5</sup>I'm of the opinion that it's *too* complicated, and deserves to be split up the way `git checkout` got split into `git switch` and `git restore`.  Of course for compatibility purposes, there will still be a `git reset`, just as Git 2.23 and later still have `git checkout`, even after the split-up.

<sup>6</sup>`git restore` is actually *more* powerful because you can pick *any* commit, not just the current one, and you can choose whether to copy it to Git's index, your work-tree, or both.  So if `git reset` *were* split up as I am thinking of in footnote 5, one of the two commands would be `git restore`.

---

#### Conclusion

What `git reset` does, after successfully modifying some of the index copies of files, is run a partial `git status`.  This compares the index copies of files to your work-tree copies.  It doesn't *just* compare files that were individually re-set, but rather *all* index entries.  Since the index lists *every file that will be in the next commit*, this can be a lot of files.

Note that what you are doing, as you modify files and then run `git add`, is arranging the *intermediate* copies of each file, in Git's "staging area" (index), so as to arrange everything *for* the next commit.  This is why we call it the *staging area:* we put particular copies of particular files "up on stage", and then take a photographic snapshot that we call a commit.  That commit is built from what's on the *stage*, which isn't necessarily the same as what you are working with.

Other version control systems don't do this: they don't *have* a separate staging area, and when you make a new commit, they snapshot your working tree.  This has its own pluses and minuses, and winds up needing a list of files (often called a *manifest*) since working trees tend to have a lot of files in them that *shouldn't* be committed.  Git uses its index for this purpose: if you don't copy a file *into* the index—i.e., don't put it up "on stage" for the later snapshot—it won't be in the snapshot.

But, because the index has a full copy of every file, that makes three copies, which makes for these odd situations.  Since you can't *see* the index copy, you need something—`git status`, usually—that will *compare* the index copies against the working tree copies, and let you know if you want to update your proposed next commit.  We "see" the index by its shadows: when it matches the current commit and/or work-tree, we don't see anything.  Having fewer shadows makes the ones that *are* there stand out, so this works fairly well.  But it's tricky!